# Do I need to close expired connections in Apache HTTPAsyncClient?

Tags: connection, apache-httpcomponents

Do I need to close expired connections in Apache HttpAsyncClient as is done with HttpClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just double-checked the source code. Yes, one still has to explicitly evict expired connections from the pool. *However*, the underlying NIO channel and socket will get closed and released immediately. The problem with expired connections not being automatically evicted from the pool is a bug in HttpAsyncClient 4.0 beta3. Feel free to raise a JIRA for this defect.