# Java HttpClient number of Connections to a host

Tags: java, multithreading, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an HttpClient initiating GET requests to a Web application. I am using the HttpComponents Apache Library.

I set up the connection manager as below.

```
public synchronized static void registerCnalHttpClient(final Parameters params) {


         final int maxTotalConnections = 
           Integer.valueOf(params.get("max_total_connections", "100"));
        final int defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost = 
           Integer.valueOf(params.get("def_max_connections_per_host",
                "50"));
        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = 
              new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConnections);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost);

        final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager);
        httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
        esb.put(CNAL_HTTPCLIENT_STR, httpClient);

    }
}
```

However where I netstat from linux server running the httpClient application I never see more than 13 connections to the server I issue the request to.

Am I doing something wrongly here? The application is a multithreaded one that is why I went for the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager() class.

For completeness the code below shows how I use the httpClient to make the requests

```
 final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
 try {
      final CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = cnalHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
     try {
         final HttpEntity responseEntity = closeableHttpResponse.getEntity();
         if (responseEntity != null) {
          final InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();
          final ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(responseEntity);
          final Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
          response = IOUtils.toString(is, charset);

          final Map<String, String> m =
               ProjectStringUtils.splitURLQuery(response.trim());

              ...
            }catch(...)
            finally {
              try {
                closeableHttpResponse.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                       }
                }
           catch(...)
```

I would expect to have around 200 connections since that is the def_max_connections_per_host that I have set. The guys hosting the application I am sending the requests to say that they do not limit the concurrent connections allowed from my end.

Any ideas?

Comment: and aren't the requests just completed too fast on the server?

Comment: The thing is that most of the times the requests take a long time to complete. Sometimes it is up to 60 seconds (when of course I have set the appropriate timeout values). also I generate huge number of requests processes that lead to http requests (around 100K) so I would expect to have many shown at any given time I netstat

Comment: maybe write an interceptor for the pool to count what's happening? or turn some fine logging on? or isn't it this by chance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032070/do-i-need-to-close-expired-connections-in-apache-httpasyncclient

Comment: and are you sure the server isn't rejecting too many connections from one place?

Comment: I do not know the last part... the people responsible for the server say that they do not drop anything. Is there a standard way to implement the interceptor? I don't think it is related to the link you have sent.. at least from what I understand of it.